# img src tag not working

Tags: html

I have uploaded my website however the img src tag do not work , as the pic is not visible, how can I rectify it.
In img src tag has the path where that pic is on my local machine.

> img src="D:\Office\Website\Dance floor experiment\pages\video\HTMLContentScroller\assets\Corporate.jpg"

this is the path that I have

Thanks

Comment: Paste your code here, please. We cannot help you with so few infos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload website on a webserver, your img source, `src`, should reference an image that is publicly available.

Upload the image on your local machine to your webserver and change the `src` to reference that.

Comment: I tried doing the same but it didnt work, heres the path that i changed to 
<img src="/public_html/pages/video/HTMLContentScroller/assets/skin/Corporate.jpg"

Comment: remove `/public` from your `src`

Answer (score 1):

Your website cannot access your local machine(as it is hosted on another machine--the server) and therefore it cannot find the image file it is looking for.

You have to upload the image file to the server and provide the path there.

Say if you upload the image file in the root folder, the src can simply be the "filename.extension". Just check the file path accordingly where you put the image file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative paths when referencing images on a page. Let's assume that your page file is in the 'Office\Website\' folder, your image tag will be:

```
<img src="Dance floor experiment\pages\video\HTMLContentScroller\assets\Corporate.jpg">
```

Comment: I am just trying that, its been uploaded, hopefully it should work,finger crossed.